# How to take a section of a file and write those lines to an array in C#

Tags: c#

If I have a file that reads:

SECTION_00

*several lines of data

SECTION_01

*several lines of data

I want to start with the line SECTION_00 and write that line and all the lines under it to an array of lines until it reaches SECTION_01.  Then do the same thing again with SECTION_01 into a different array.

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: Welcome.  Your question is too broad.  [ask]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Post a sample of the text file showing multiple sections.  I've been parsing text files for a very long time and trying to describe a text file in words never works.  You need to see the spaces and text exactly as they appear to get the parsing to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
string filePath = "Path";
string content = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
string[] sections = content.Split(new string[] {"SECTION_00", "SECTION_01"});

string section00 = sections[0];
string section01 = sections[1];
```

Add more sections in the Split() string array